# Is there any way to return the name of the control I click on in winform App

Tags: c#, .net

I have 10 checkboxes in a form... and what i want is when i right click on a checkbox and click edit on the contextmenu then the text value of the checkbox should change..
so what i want is to target the checkbox and that check box out of 10 on whihc i have right clicked..
cant even use sender object as sender object will return "Edit" as we are clicking on the Edit on the context menu..

Comment: What class do you use for context menu?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have several checkboxes on form and one ContextMenuStrip which assigned for each checkbox. You can obtain checkbox object in contex menu item click handler as shown below:

```
    private void changeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox myCheckbox = (((sender as ToolStripDropDownItem).Owner as ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl as CheckBox);
        myCheckbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
("Edit".Parent as ContextMenu/ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl
```

Answer (score -1):

Attach to the `MouseDown` event on the checkbox control and see if the right mouse button was clicked (`MouseButtons.Right`) and store it in a variable like `currentCheckBox` which you then can reference.